# foreach loop is echoing the results of the first submission

Tags: php, xml, rest

I'm working with data from Formstack's REST API. Everything is in XML format. I wrote some PHP to process it, and for some reason when I echo $valueVar in a foreach loop only the value from the first entry is returning for each of the three entries. I really don't know why the string isn't getting replaced. Could someone please shed some light on what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you!

[PHP Output](https://www.harpercollege.edu/dev/formstack-api-tests/dreams.php)

[Formstack API XML Output](https://www.harpercollege.edu/dev/formstack-api-tests/submission.xml)

```
foreach($xml->submissions->submission as $submission) {
    foreach($xml->submissions->submission->data->XML_Serializer_Tag as $serializer) {
        $fieldeVar = (string)$serializer->field;
        $valueVar = (string)$serializer->value;
        if ($fieldeVar=="95733876") {
            echo $valueVar;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you remove `break;`? https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php

Comment: It results in the same output. 
https://www.harpercollege.edu/dev/formstack-api-tests/dreams-no-break.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a simple case of your 2 loops clobbering each other. Notice how you're defining the inner loop as `foreach($xml->submissions->submission->...`. That will always grab the first instance. It should be using `$submission` which your outer loop is setting up for you.

Just change

```
foreach($xml->submissions->submission as $submission) {
    foreach($xml->submissions->submission->data->XML_Serializer_Tag as $serializer) {
```

to this

```
foreach ($xml->submissions->submission as $submission) {
    foreach ($submission->data->XML_Serializer_Tag as $serializer) {
```

Output

> prefix = Dr first = Argnes last = Acmefirst = Bobby last =
> Leamalotfirst = Tina last = Students

Comment: Matt that worked perfectly. Its always the small things that drive us crazy. Thank you so much..!